# How can I get unique fields when building a table using Common Table Expression (CTE) in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, datetime, common-table-expression, generate-series

I'm trying to generate a series of timestamps, calculate the day of the week for each timestamp and select only timestamps that fall Monday - Saturday, using PostGreSQL.

Here's my attempt so far:

```
WITH
candidates AS (SELECT * FROM generate_series(
  date_trunc('hour', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '2 hours'),
  date_trunc('hour', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '2 hours')+INTERVAL '1 week',
  INTERVAL '1 hour')),
candidows AS (SELECT EXTRACT(DOW FROM generate_series) FROM candidates),
candidatable AS (SELECT b.date_part AS dow, a.generate_series as start_booking FROM candidates a, candidows b)
SELECT * FROM candidatable WHERE dow != 0;
```

The view returned includes a dow column which behaves as I expect, but the start_booking column just contains the same value repeated:

```
 dow |     start_booking
-----+------------------------
   2 | 2017-09-19 11:00:00+01
   2 | 2017-09-19 11:00:00+01
   2 | 2017-09-19 11:00:00+01
   2 | 2017-09-19 11:00:00+01
   2 | 2017-09-19 11:00:00+01
   2 | 2017-09-19 11:00:00+01
   2 | 2017-09-19 11:00:00+01
   2 | 2017-09-19 11:00:00+01
   2 | 2017-09-19 11:00:00+01
   2 | 2017-09-19 11:00:00+01
   2 | 2017-09-19 11:00:00+01
   2 | 2017-09-19 11:00:00+01
   2 | 2017-09-19 11:00:00+01
   3 | 2017-09-19 11:00:00+01
   3 | 2017-09-19 11:00:00+01
   3 | 2017-09-19 11:00:00+01
```

If I replace the last SELECT statement with:

```
SELECT * FROM candidates;
```

Then the data I'm trying to view as start_booking above are sequential, as I expect:

```
    generate_series
------------------------
 2017-09-19 11:00:00+01
 2017-09-19 12:00:00+01
 2017-09-19 13:00:00+01
 2017-09-19 14:00:00+01
 2017-09-19 15:00:00+01
 2017-09-19 16:00:00+01
```

What can I do to get the data from candidates.generate_series to appear as candidatables.start_booking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a wild guess - are you trying to:

```
WITH
candidates AS (SELECT generate_series start_booking, EXTRACT(DOW FROM generate_series) dow FROM generate_series(
  date_trunc('hour', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '2 hours'),
  date_trunc('hour', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '2 hours')+INTERVAL '1 week',
  INTERVAL '1 hour'))
SELECT * FROM candidates WHERE dow != 0;
```

?..

Comment: This is better behaviour alright, but I don't really want the result to include a column called "generate_series".  Can I rename that somehow?

Comment: eddited to include wanted alias